# Is it possible to edit Delimited Text Layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, attribute-table

GIS beginner here...

I have a tab-delimited text file that I'm importing into QGIS just fine. But I try to edit the attribute table, the little pencil-looking button is grayed out, and it's not letting me edit it via the QuickMultiAttributeEdit plugin either.

I've googled around a lot, but can't for the life of me figure out how to make the attribute table editable. Any help?

Thanks all!

Comment: QuickMultiAttributeEdit is for geomtery and associated attributes - use notepad++ for tab-delimited editing

Answer (score 5):

Delimited text layers are not editable. It's simply not supported.

To me, it makes more sense to prepare the text file in a text editor before loading the finished file into QGIS where it can be turned into a proper spatial (file) format.

Answer (score 1):

After you import your data on the delimited text layer, you can save is as .shp and then you can edit it. Try it out