# Adding attributes to CSV-file using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, csv

I am new to PyQGIS and I want to add one more field in my existed table. Here is my code:

```
pointLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'my_layer', 'delimitedtext')
pointLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("new1", QVariant.Double)])
pointLayer.updateFields()
```

However, there's no difference if I print the names of the field before and after adding attributes respectively.

[image]

I don't know how to fix the problem and the code does not have any error.

Comment: It does not seem possible to edit delimited text layers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31994/is-it-possible-to-edit-delimited-text-layers-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: you can't if using "delimitedtext" option to open CSV, you can if using "ogr" to open the layer. The 2nd choice restrict what you can do when opening compared to the 1st option and you will be **limited** by what ogr can do (see driver info behind QGIS scene https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html#creation-issues). Last option: do not choose CSV to add fields as it can't keep types in columns when you reopen. Choose another format and export to CSV if you really have the requirements

**Option 1**:

Proof to show you can't edit using "delimitedtext" layer by running below code after selecting your CSV layer:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
cap = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
if cap & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
    print('Allows addition of new attributes (fields)')
else:
    print('Do not allows addition of new attributes (fields)')
```

You can also use a version to summarize all capabilities by running

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer.dataProvider().capabilitiesString())
```

For a shp, it will return `Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Rename Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Create Attribute Indexes, Fast Access to Features at ID, Change Geometries`

For a delimited txt, it will return `Create Spatial Index, Fast Access to Features at ID, Curved Geometries`. In 2nd case, as `Add Attributes` is missing you interpret it's not possible.

You can test other properties related to the provider capabilities using list from https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a1a360c9e78933697b9f9be334cfcaf7a

**Option 2**:

If you really want to edit using `ogr`, the recipe below works

```py
pointLayer = QgsVectorLayer('/tmp/test1.csv|layername=test1|option:X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=X|option:Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Y', 'my_layer', 'ogr')
pointLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("new1", QVariant.Double)])
pointLayer.updateFields()
```

Content of file `test1.csv`

```
point_id,X,Y,ele,time,Ds,len
"371",0.6644, 45.89,486,2020/04/07 09:58:07,0,0
"372",1.2697,44.38,486.2,2020/04/07 09:58:08,8.544,8.54
```